# How to join these 2 tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these tables. I need to be able to apply this formula: 
**sal = sal - tax * sal**.

To do that, I assume that I need to join somehow the table emp with salgrade. How could I do that, since I don't have any common field?

```
Name     Null     Type        
-------- -------- ----------- 
EMPNO    NOT NULL NUMBER(4)   
ENAME             CHAR(10)    
JOB               CHAR(9)     
MGR               NUMBER(4)   
HIREDATE          DATE        
SAL               NUMBER(7,2) 
COMM              NUMBER(7,2) 
DEPTNO            NUMBER(2)   

desc salgrade
Name      Null Type        
--------- ---- ----------- 
GRADE          NUMBER(5)   
LOSAL          NUMBER(7)   
HISAL          NUMBER(7)   
TAX            NUMBER(5,2) 
SENIORITY      NUMBER(2)
```

Comment: How do you know which salgrade belongs to which emp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join them where `emp.sal` is between `salgrade.losal` and `salgrade.hisal`

For example:

```
SELECT (sal - (tax * sal)) AS Sal_result
  FROM emp
  JOIN salgrade ON (emp.sal BETWEEN salgrade.lowsal AND salgrade.hisal)
```

Of course that is assuming that there is no other linking table that you have not mentioned and that the emp.sal being between the losal and hisal value is a valid link.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Good ideea. Working just perfect. Thank you :) And another question, how could apply that for the user with id 1000 for example? Adding WHERE emp.empno = '1000' is not a solution.

Comment: No worries, if it's all OK, I'd appreciate if you mark the answer as correct.

Comment: You should really ask another question rather than asking one in a comment. What do you mean adding the WHERE clause is not a solution? Why not? Do you get an error (bearing in mind empno is a NUMBER and you are comparing it to a VARCHAR by putting quotes round the 1000)?